# Tracking email newsletter with piwik

Tags: email, tracking, newsletter, matomo

I want to track email newsletter especially with piwik.
Now there's the following image tracking code given ([source](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/)):

```
<!-- Piwik Image Tracker -->
<img src="http://analytics.mysite.net/piwik.php?idsite={$IDSITE}amp;rec=1" style="border:0" alt="" />
<!-- End Piwik -->
```

I want to add something like `_rcn` to attach a [campaign](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-campaigns/), to assign the email opening.
The code could look like that (web beacon):

```
<img src="http://analytics.mysite.net/piwik.php?idsite=1&rec=1&_rcn=mycampaign" style="border: 0; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0;padding: 0" alt="" />
```

But that doesn't work... Any Ideas?

Comment: That seems about right, are you sure images are not blocked by email clients? Is it just the campaign tracking that doesn't work or all tracking?

Comment: Generally the tracking... I don't get a working campaign into the img-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found something. My first attempt was right xD

```
<!-- Piwik Image Tracker -->
<img src="http://analytics.mysite.net/piwik.php?idsite={$IDSITE}&action_name=test&_rcn=testcampaign&rec=1" style="border:0" alt="" />
<!-- End Piwik -->
```

Thats working o.O

Just set {$IDSITE} to your site id, for example: 1

Parameters:

```
rec – (required) The parameter &rec=1 is required to force the request to be recorded
idsite – (required) Defines the Website ID being tracked
_rcn - the campaign name
```

More: http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/

The action_name ist tracked as simple site, I don't know why and the request ist shown as visitor. AND with _rcn you can set a campaign.

Thats it.